# Fusion charts dynamic clickable

Tags: fusioncharts, linegraph

I have a scenario where in I am using fusion chart which has a multiple line chart in one fusion chart. I want to create a clickable line chart where in clicking on label that particular attribute will be displayed in graph. So basically each line chart in graph is dynamically displayed with click of button for each line chart. I hope you get my requirement. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your requirement correctly.

As far as I know, FusionCharts v3.2 has something similar to what you require.

From the documentation,

> Interactive legends in charts that allow for selective showing/hiding of data series (or slicing, in case of pie charts)

You can see a demo of this at [FusionCharts gallery](http://www.fusioncharts.com/gallery/Category.asp?LineArea)